# Use of **kwargs in a function as variable?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a function that plots a map.

```
def plot(country, year1, year2, month, obs,**kwargs):
```

And I have a plotly express function to plot a scatter mapbox:

```
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df_to_plot, 
                        lat="LATITUDE",#latitude of the station 
                        lon="LONGITUDE", #longitude of the station
                        hover_name = "NAME", #when hovered, show the name of the station
                        color = "coef", #color differs by coef
                        zoom=zoom, #default zoom size.
                        mapbox_style = mapbox_style, #style of the plot.
                       color_continuous_scale=color_continuous_scale, #scale of the colorbar, red to gray countinuous.

...
```

Here, I want to pass parameters for `zoom, mapbox_style, color_continuous_scale`.

However, when I call the function and pass the parameters:

```
fig =plot("India", 1980, 2020, 1, 
                                   obs = 10,
                                   zoom = 2,
                                   mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                                   color_continuous_scale=color_map)
```

I get an error: name 'zoom' is not defined.

Maybe I am using the `**Kwargs` wrong. How do I pass the parameters manually and use them in the function?

Comment: `kwargs` is a dictionary, so you want `kwargs['zoom']`. But if your function is meant to accept a keyword argument named `zoom`, why not just give it one?

Comment: `**kwargs` is used when you don't know the exact number of parameters to pass. At that point, we use **kwags in which we pass a dictionary as parameter and that dictionary can be used in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are mandatory argument for `plot`, just accept the arguments by name like all the rest; you can make them keyword-only if you like by putting them after a `*` (without a name, it makes the rest keyword-only; with a name, it would allow arbitrary additional positional arguments, so probably not a good idea here):

```
def plot(country, year1, year2, month, obs, *, zoom, mapbox_style, color_continuous_scale):
```

and the body of `plot` doesn't change.

If those arguments aren't always needed, and there's a wide variety of arguments you sometimes need in different code paths, you just need to know that `**kwargs` collects them as a string keyed `dict` (you can't dynamically allocate space for a variable number of locals, so actually making `zoom` conditionally defined as a raw name in local scope isn't possible), so look up the extra names the same way you would on a `dict`, e.g.:

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df_to_plot, 
                        lat="LATITUDE",#latitude of the station 
                        lon="LONGITUDE", #longitude of the station
                        hover_name="NAME", #when hovered, show the name of the station
                        color="coef", #color differs by coef
                        zoom=kwargs['zoom'], #default zoom size.
                        mapbox_style=kwargs['mapbox_style'], #style of the plot.
                        color_continuous_scale=kwargs['color_continuous_scale'], #scale of the colorbar, red to gray countinuous.
```

and you'll get a `KeyError` at lookup time if it turns out the caller failed to provide them.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the keyword arguments from `plot` function to the `plotly` function like this:

```
px.scatter_mapbolx(..., **kwargs)
```

No need to specify each keyword argument.

Also you can specify keyword arguments in plot and then pass them to the plotly function.

```
def plot(..., zoom, mapbox_style, ...):
```

And optionally give default arguments:

```
def plot(..., zoom=1, mapbox_style=None, ...):
```

But dont mix the 2 approaches. If you use `**kwargs` as argument in the plot definition, then call the plotly function with `**kwargs` at last.

If you use indivdual keyword arguments in the `plot` function definition, then pass them to the plotly function as individual keyword arguments.